# Is the Brain of Cthulhu a hard mode boss?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is the Brain a hard mode boss?

Answer (score 4):

No, Brain of Cuthulu is not in hard mode. Typically he is the second boss that you fight.

You will trigger hard mode once you defeat the Wall of Flesh.

Answer (score 2):

No he is not, It is a boss in easy mode. The hard mode bosses are very hard. You must defeat the wall of flesh to unlock the hard mode bosses, these are: The Twins, The Destroyer, Skeletron Prime, Plantera or Golem.